# Как перевести float массив в bufferedImage?

Tags: java

Пытался найти инфу, но так ничего и не подошло.
Вот метод, который я использовал:

```
public static BufferedImage getImageFromArray(int[] pixels) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    image.setRGB(0, 0, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, pixels, 0, 0);
    return image;
}
```

в итоге так и не смог сохранить изображение полученное из массива.
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: А где тут массив float ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать Raster получив его из BufferedImage

```
public static BufferedImage getImageFromArray(float[] pixels) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    raster.setPixels(0, 0, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, pixels);

    return image;
}
```